# Having trouble creating and Event in Google Calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement the google calendar api in my Flutter app. I have successfully implemented firebase auth, Google_sign_in and requesting permissions to modify calendars.

I can retrieve my primary calendar no problem. I have run into difficulty in understanding how to go about inserting an event.

I'm looking for is an example of how to use the api.

I've tried following the javascript samples but there's too much of a disconnect between javascript and dart for a beginner to piece together.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' show json;

DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime endTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 2));
var authHeaders;

Future handleGetCalendar(user) async {
    final http.Response responseCal = await http.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary',
    headers: await user.authHeaders,
);
authHeaders = user.authHeaders;

if (responseCal.statusCode != 200) {
    print('Not OK');
}

final Map data = json.decode(responseCal.body);
print(data);
}

Map<String, dynamic> eventMap = {
    'calenderID': 'primary',
    'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer 
    products.',
    'start': {
    'dateTime': startTime.toIso8601String(),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    'end': {
    'dateTime': endTime.toIso8601String(),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
};


Future<void> handleCreateEvent() async {
//This is as far as I have gotten.  
CalendarApi(http.Client()).events.insert(Event.fromJson(eventMap), 
'primary');
}
```

I believe the issue is to do with sending an authenticated request but I don't know how to create a "Client".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer https://pub.dev/packages/http. Readme has instructions on how to create a client with auth headers

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you.